regular expression negative lookahead not follow a pattern of character
Given the following string
abcdefabcghi.xml (want to match abcghi.xml)
abcdefabc.xml (want to match abc.xml)
abc.xml (want to match abc.xml, whole string)
I want my regular expression to match the last abc*.xml, how to do this?
I try to use negative lookahead as follow but fail
abc.*?(?!abc)\.xml 


With your shown samples please try following regex (^abc)(?:.*?)?(\.xml)$ Here is the Online demo https://regex101.com/r/AT7MGO/1 for same.

Obviously abc does not match .xml so your lookahead does nothing. It's really not clear to me what you are hoping to accomplish.

You can put the negative lookahead after matching abc, and then match .xml like abc(?!.*abc).*?\.xml See https://regex101.com/r/7jABXV/1 Or abc(?:(?!abc|\.xml).)*\.xml https://regex101.com/r/ikD8WD/1

@Thefourthbird the answer abc(?!.abc).?.xml is exactly what I want, thanks.

Use the following regex:
.*(abc.*?.xml)

And fetch the first group, which will give you requested results - sample.
